# Javascript function not executing until after loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to loop through an array that contains product numbers among other things (price, quantity, etc..). The product number is used to generate an image which is called in a different function. When I call the function and pass the loop variable to it, nothing happens until the loop completes. Then all the product images are generated, but they are the same. I'm at a loss.

```
for (var g = 0, len = oldDetails.length; g <= len - 1; g++) {
    loaditem (oldDetails[g]['product_number'],g);
}
function loaditem (itemnumber, itemlocation) {
     document.getElementById('divid' + itemlocation).innerHTML = '<img src = "' + itemnumber + '.jpg" />';
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

***EDIT*** I'm posting the full code for reference

```js
      //alert (JSON.stringify(oldDetails));
     setTimeout(function() {
       for (var g = 0, len = oldDetails.length; g <= len - 1; g++) {
         count = 'somestring' + g;
         loaditem(oldDetails[g]['product_number'], count);
         if (g < len - 1) {
           duplicate();
         }
       }
     }, 1000);

     function loaditem(newItemNumber, count) {
       itemNumber = newItemNumber.toUpperCase();
       //ARMS Handler
       switch (itemNumber.substring(0, 1)) {
         case 'A':
           lookupNumber = itemNumber.replace(itemNumber.substring(2, 3), '0');
           break;
         case 'R':
           lookupNumber = itemNumber.replace(itemNumber.substring(2, 3), '0');
           break;
         case 'M':
           lookupNumber = itemNumber.replace(itemNumber.substring(2, 3), '0');
           break;
         case 'N':
           lookupNumber = itemNumber.replace(itemNumber.substring(2, 3), '0');
           break;
         default:
           lookupNumber = itemNumber;
       }
       //dash handler
       if (itemNumber.substring(4, 5) == '-') {} else {
         lookupNumber = lookupNumber.replace('-', '');
       }
       count = count.substr(count.length - 1, count.length);
       orderDetails[count][0] = itemNumber; //adds product # to orderDetail array
       imgSource = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/images2.eprevue.net/p4dbimg/767/image480/' + lookupNumber.toLowerCase() + '_con.jpg';
       var imageTest = $("<img>");
       var imageTest_con = $("<img>");
       imageTest.attr('src', imgSource).load(function() {
           document.getElementById("product-image" + count).innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgSource + '" width="100%" height="auto" />';
         })
         .error(function() {
           imgSource = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/images2.eprevue.net/p4dbimg/767/image480/' + lookupNumber.toLowerCase() + '.jpg';
           imageTest_con.attr('src', imgSource).load(function() {
               document.getElementById("product-image" + count).innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgSource + '" width="100%" height="auto" />';
             })
             .error(function() {
               imgSource = 'http://hekmancontract.andrewchristmann.com/quote-sheet/images/image-missing.jpg';
               document.getElementById("product-image" + count).innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgSource + '" width="100%" height="auto" />';
             });
         });

       document.getElementById('pnum' + count).innerHTML = " " + itemNumber.toUpperCase();
     }
```

Comment: Your for loop syntax is wrong. You should have only three statements in there. for(var g = 0; len <= oldDtails.length; g++)

Comment: @glcheetham that is incorrect...

Comment: That code should work. Are you sure the data source is different?

Comment: You should post the `oldDetails` contents

Comment: Offtopic, So far I know length gets automatically handled nowadays so no need to store it in a var. No performance gain, only readability issues. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli oldDetails[g]['product_number'] = N7001. I abbreviated the code a bit but it links like so...http://s3.amazon.com/**more links**/product_number.jpg

Comment: @AndrewC. we need to see some real data to understand if the problem is with the data. Your script has no problem, but if all the elements in the `oldDetails` array have the same value for their `product_number` property then it is natural to see the same image.

Comment: @epascarello the code kind of works. It places the image associated with the last product number in the array into all the divs.

Comment: So is that your exact code... because what you are saying does not line up with that code.

Comment: @epascarello exact code has been posted. It has a couple operators to handle dashes and unfound images and such.

Comment: @AndrewC. added an answer that explains the actual problem with the ***real*** code.

Comment: should be good lesson as to why to always use `var` ... bugs are hard to find when you don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you posted the full code the problem can be pinpointed at 
to the global variables you use in the `loaditem` method.

If you convert them to local (*as you should since they are altered for each iteration*) it should work.

Something like this

```js
function loaditem(newItemNumber, count) {
  var itemNumber = newItemNumber.toUpperCase(),
      lookupNumber;
  //ARMS Handler
  switch (itemNumber.substring(0, 1)) {
    case 'A':
      lookupNumber = itemNumber.replace(itemNumber.substring(2, 3), '0');
      break;
    case 'R':
      lookupNumber = itemNumber.replace(itemNumber.substring(2, 3), '0');
      break;
    case 'M':
      lookupNumber = itemNumber.replace(itemNumber.substring(2, 3), '0');
      break;
    case 'N':
      lookupNumber = itemNumber.replace(itemNumber.substring(2, 3), '0');
      break;
    default:
      lookupNumber = itemNumber;
  }
  //dash handler
  if (itemNumber.substring(4, 5) == '-') {} else {
    lookupNumber = lookupNumber.replace('-', '');
  }
  count = count.substr(count.length - 1, count.length);
  orderDetails[count][0] = itemNumber; //adds product # to orderDetail array
  var imgSource = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/images2.eprevue.net/p4dbimg/767/image480/' + lookupNumber.toLowerCase() + '_con.jpg';
  var imageTest = $("<img>");
  var imageTest_con = $("<img>");
  imageTest.attr('src', imgSource).load(function() {
      document.getElementById("product-image" + count).innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgSource + '" width="100%" height="auto" />';
    })
    .error(function() {
      imgSource = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/images2.eprevue.net/p4dbimg/767/image480/' + lookupNumber.toLowerCase() + '.jpg';
      imageTest_con.attr('src', imgSource).load(function() {
          document.getElementById("product-image" + count).innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgSource + '" width="100%" height="auto" />';
        })
        .error(function() {
          imgSource = 'http://hekmancontract.andrewchristmann.com/quote-sheet/images/image-missing.jpg';
          document.getElementById("product-image" + count).innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgSource + '" width="100%" height="auto" />';
        });
    });

  document.getElementById('pnum' + count).innerHTML = " " + itemNumber.toUpperCase();
}
```

---

So the issue was that you declared some global variables and at the same time you were setting some asynchronous callbacks (*the `load` and `error` events*) that used those variables.

The global variables would be altered for each iteration of the loop that calls the `loadItem` while the actual value of these global variables would be used **when** the image was loaded (*asynchronously*). So until the images have loaded the `imgSource` variable would have changed its values and would then get used for the actual DOM `img` insertion.

Comment: Didn't know that not putting 'var' in front of the variables declared them as global. That solved the problem, thank you. For reference, I also had to add var to the count variable as well.

Comment: Lesson learned BTW to not assume I know what the problem is. The more code the better.

Comment: @AndrewC. Did it not work without the `var count`? Because `count` is local due to being a parameter of the function.

Comment: without 'var count' it did not work. You've been very helpful and solved the issue, but for my understanding, I don't get what it would matter if the variable is global or not. My understanding is that global variables apply across all functions, local, well are localized. Since the ''for' statement is redefining global count', I don't follow why it matters since the variable is redefined every time it loops. Got a brief explanation?